# Make Rigid Body sim to respect array modifier

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to build a simulation, where Cubes will fall when arrayed floor is shrinking.

But nothing happens, when animation goes from top to bottom position. I am curious why?
[image]

**Floor settings**, gravity is turned on

[image]

[image]